# display message many time in Assembly language

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, nasm, dos

I'm trying to display a message several times.

I used nasm and I used this program :

```
    MOV cx, 1
    mov  ax, 10
re:
    CMP ax, cx
    JS fin
    mov  dx, texte 
    INC cx
    JMP re
fin:
    Int 21h
    texte: db 'Hello, World !!'
```

Comment: What's the problem? (also, it doesn't look like you're initializing `ax`)

Comment: The problem tnis code not display the message Hello, World !! 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple more things:

- for int21h to perform output, you need to set AH to 9. You're already using AX to store the loop limit; you'd have to use some other register (BX, SI, DI are currently unused), or a hard-coded limit. Also, int21h function 9 changes the value of AL on output - one more reason not to use AX.
- The string needs to be terminated with the $ character. That's what int21h/9  expects, not an convention of assembly language in general.
- And, like obe said, you want the int 21h command before, not after the "jmp re" line.
- At the "fin" label, you might want to quit the program. The sequence for that is: "mov ah, 4ch/int 21h".

Comment: Or count CX down from 10, instead of using two registers to loop from 1 to 10.  Or put the 10 as an immediate operand for CMP.  SI and DI are also unused, IDK why you mentioned BX but not them.

Comment: Many ways to do this. "LOOP re" command would probably be the easiest.

Comment: Except that [LOOP is slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently), and not a good habit to teach beginners.  They won't find real code that uses it when looking at compiler output, so might as well learn to make loops with cmp/jcc (or dec/jnz).  It's simpler just to never mention LOOP in the first place, since it's not useful outside of optimizing for code-size.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you invoke `int 21h` only at the bottom.
Try to move it into the loop.

Also, it's been a really long time since I last did anything in assembly but you probably also need to prepare some registers to determine what `int 21h` would do. See more info here: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09

Comment: I change it and I used the nasm command but the message is not displayed.

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question. Instead, append the updated code below.